# Passing props with asynchronous data

Tags: reactjs, dictionary

I am wondering what is the correct way of passing props and then mapping over them when the props need to be fetched first and aren't ready at page load.

The `map` currently breaks the page because the array is undefined when the page loads before the data is fetched and passed as props.

Summary of events:

1. Parent component makes API GET request which puts response into state
2. Parent component passes info from state to child component (named SearchResults)

   `<SearchResults results={this.state.results} />`

This is what the child component looks like.

```
const SearchResults = (props) => {

    const items = props.results.items.map(item => {
        return (
            <div>{item.url}</div>
        )
    })

    return (
        <div className="results">
          <h3>Results:</h3>

        {items}

        </div>
    )
}
```

I was considering the following but am wondering what is a good way.

- Lifecycle like `componentDidMount()` or `componentWillReceiveProps()`
- Using an `if` statement to check if props is defined - but limits access to variables inside the `if` block
- Using `default props`
- Would loading the props into the child's state work?

Comment: ...or just don't render Child until data is fetched: `{this.state.results && <SearchResults results={this.state.results} />}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Think-Twice points out, we're making an assumption about the parent component's state.

In the parent component, we need something like:

```
constructor() {
  this.state = {
    results: {items: []}
  }
}
```

Then in it's render method we can do

```
{this.state.results.items.length ? <SearchResults results={this.state.results} /> : null}
```

This way the component won't render until there are some results.

To further validate the results you can set proptypes on `SearchResults`, something like:

`import PropTypes from "prop-types";`

```
SearchResults.propTypes = {
  results: PropTypes.shape({
    items: PropTypes.array
  })
}
```

Comment: What if results is not an array or initial value is undefined? Will the length still work?

Comment: @Think-Twice if you want to validate props, use PropTypes

Comment: @Think-Twice, no, it will not. so either `this.state.results && this.state.results.length && ...` or using [babel's optional-chaining](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/next/babel-plugin-proposal-optional-chaining.html) plugin `this.state.results?.length && `

Comment: I see your point. We didn't get to see what the initial `state.results` data structure is. So yeah it might fail if they don't initialize it as an empty array.

Comment: @James Agree with that but OP is doing .map on nested array so what if results doesn't contain items then

Comment: Ok Though we define prop type for results as an object, initially it will be an empty object so on first render this.state.results.items or this.state.results.items.length would fail. Isn't it?

Comment: @Think-Twice Thats true. I read this question as being less about validation and more about how to properly use react lifecycle methods, or not at all in this case. I'm assuming they'll figure out how to validate their data.

Comment: When I do `this.state.results && this.state.results.length && ...` it is literally drawing a 0 on the page to represent the length. What am I doing wrong? The state for results is initialized as an empty array. When I use `this.state.results.items.length && ...` it causes an error 'cannot read length of undefined'.

Comment: @James Thanks, I was initializing state as `results: []` not `results: {items: []}`, which was part of my problem. Still when I use the way you suggested a '0' gets drawn to the page for the length. It seems to be working with via the code in my comment of other answer.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your Api returns an object so in constructor initialise results as an object but not an array. The below conditional check will make sure it doesn’t throw any error when results is set to undefined by Api response or results doesn’t contain items or items is not an array. So these conditional checks required to be on safer side which make sure results is an object and contains items key in it and items is an array.

If you directly check this.state.results.items then when Api response doesn’t contain items key the code will fail or items is not an array the code will fail so it’s good to do necessary checks before doing .map

```
const SearchResults = (props) => {
    const { results } = props;
    const items = results && results.items && Array.isArray(results.items) && props.results.items.map(item => {
        return (
            <div>{item.url}</div>
        )
    })

    return (
        <div className="results">
          <h3>Results:</h3>

        {items}

        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Hey this is working, thank you. But is there a shorter way?

Comment: Using this condition seems to be working for me in the child component:

`const items = props.results.items && props.results.items.map...`